# Magento configurable products prices depending of multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.1, I'm trying to define a configurable product type that contains two different attributes:

```
 - Weight
 - Purity
```

So the user can buy a product selecting

```
 - 1 Kg, 5 Kg or 15 Kg package
 - 90%, 95% or 99% purity
```

The price will depend on both attributes combined. E.g.

```
 - 1 Kg  - 90% -> 1.00$
 - 1 Kg  - 95% -> 1.50$
 - 1 Kg  - 99% -> 1.90$
 - 5 Kg  - 90% -> 4.50$
 - 5 Kg  - 95% -> 6.50$
 - 5 Kg  - 99% -> 7.90$
 - 15 Kg - 90% -> 12.00$
 - 15 Kg - 95% -> 20.00$
 - 15 Kg - 99% -> 25.00$
```

So for each attribute combination, I have defined a different price for each simple product.
I discovered that in this way Magento ignores the price defined for each simple products and allow only setting different prices for each attribute, without the possibility of combining them.

Is there a way to use the simple product price, instead of the configurable product price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box is not possible.
But you can use an extension for that.
I haven't used this one: [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) but I've seen it recommended a lot. The extension page says it works for versions up to 1.5, but you can give it a try. It seams it works for 1.8 for some people. Maybe it works on 1.9.

Comment: Would like to add some stuffs, the extension works great but when you will add product to the cart, the related simple product will be added instead of the configurable product. Hence, you will see the title of the simple product rather than configurable product.

Comment: @Dexter. Good to know. Thanks for the input.